# Adding a reference to a project not working

Tags: visual-studio, reference, unity-game-engine

http://prntscr.com/65pjv1 - VStudio. In the right you can see the Annotations reference added, down you can see that it has succeeded the built. Also you can see that UsedImplicitly(comming from JetBrains.Annotations) is found.

But unity doesn't think so: http://prntscr.com/65pjy9 - error.

This is something very simple, but obviously I am doing smth wrong. What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy fix, pretty easy. Still not that obvious. I needed to add the .dll file to the project in unity itself. Unless I did this unity coudn't find the reference that I had added previously in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `properties` of the reference file you have given `(JetBrains)` and check the path.
Now go to that path and find the corresponding file is exist or not!
If it is exist than delete `reference` and give it again and if not exist find that file and paste it to the reference path.
May this will help you.

Comment: The file is there. There's no logic removing and adding the reference again, if the file path isn't changed. Still I did it to make sure I'm not wrong and nothing happened.

Comment: That's what i will tell you further if above can't works that you need to add those dlls in to your project files and than give reference. You solved it tht's fine.